# Assign values to a 2D vector from a file on c++

Tags: c++, file, vector, 2d

Im trying to assign values to a 2d vector, this is the way that i defined the vector, and also its important to say that rows and columns, are ints previously defined

```
vector < vector <int>> vec(rows , vector <int> (columns,0));
```

i want to assign to this vector, each char of a pbm file, this file only have '1' and '0', so this is the way im reading it

```
char i;
FILE* fp;
fp = fopen("file.pbm", "r");
```

on this way im assigning values to the vector

```
for (int h=0; h<rows; h++){
    for (int j=0; j<columns; j++){ 
        while((i=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
            vec[h][j] = i;
        }
    } 
}
```

but when i try to print all the vector content, this one, only have '0'

```
for (int h=0; h<rows; h++){
        for (int j=0; j<columns; j++) 
            cout << vec[h][j];
    cout <<endl; 
}

fclose(fp);
```

If anyone could tell me where im failing when i make this assignment, thanks!

```
vec[h][j] = i;
```

Comment: You are reading the entire file into `vec[0][0]`.

Comment: As it looks so far, your code calls for out of bound indexes.

Comment: Wait, I take it back. Your `while` statement makes no sense.

Comment: @Beta It sort of does, since the assignment operator returns the value that gets assigned, which is the return result of `fgetc()`. The problem is `i` is a char, so if `fgetc()` returns EOF it won't work.

Comment: Why are you using C I/O in a C++ program? Also, consider what the while loop in the input part does.

Comment: All right, it now appears that the `while` statement itself may be correct (it's been a long time since I used C style I/O), but you almost certainly are reading the whole file into the first element of the array. The real solution here is to try simpler exercises first, like reading *three* characters from the file, rather than *an undetermined number* of them. Such errors are much easier to spot in simple code.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, the mistake was exactly in the while loop as all of you said, i changed that part with two fors and one while, now im using a while loop and some if statements, and increasing the indexes inside the while, thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int h=0; h<rows; h++){
    for (int j=0; j<columns; j++){ 
        while((i=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
            vec[h][j] = i;
        }
    } 
}
```

The while loop runs through the entire file without ever incrementing h and j so you are reading the whole file into the first element.  And you are doing this (rows*columns) times.

You'll need to redesign your code to read the code in correctly.

Comment: Hi solarflare, exactly that was the mistake, i changed that part of the code with this, int x = 0; int y = 0; while((i=fgetc(file))!=EOF && (x < rows) && (y < columns)){ if(y < columns - 1){ v_in[x][y] = i; y++; } else if(y = columns -1){ v_in[x][y] = i; y = 0; x++; } } and now is working fine! thanks a lot